# Initializing non-null type variable before try/catch

Tags: java, kotlin, try-catch

Say I have this block of code:

```
val cmd: CommandLine
try {
    cmd = parser.parse(options, args)
} catch (ex: ParseException) {
    // do stuff
}

// error: cmd is not initialized
val inputArg = cmd.getOptionValue("someArg")
```

I get the error because cmd is not initialized which is expected and normally I'd initialize it with a `null` value in Java but what if the type is `non-null` and I don't want to move all my logics to `try` block?

Comment: In the catch block you could return. Alternatively instead of `val cmd...` you could use `var cmd: CommandLine? = null` and check for `null` before using `cmd` in the last line.

Comment: Either check for null before using `cmd.getOptionValue("someArg")`, or in the event that the try block fails then make sure you initialize `cmd` properly inside your catch block. You know this already.....? Otherwise the simple answer is to set a blank string `inputArg = "";` if `getOptionValue("someArg")` returns null? But that would mean you would just need to add checks later in your code to account for an empty string.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hey Michael thanks! Wanna post that comment as the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options.

#### 1) You could use var

The first option is to make `cmd` a `var` and assign it a default value or null. Of course, you'll need to check for null after the try-catch if you make `cmd` nullable. (I recommend some kind of default value, maybe an `EmptyCommandLine` of some kind).

#### 2) Better yet, use try-catch as an expression

The second option is to use the try-catch as an expression like so:

```
val cmd: CommandLine = try {
        parser.parse("options", "args")
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        // Must:
        // 1) Throw, or error in some other way so as to return Nothing.
        // 2) Return a default/failed value for cmd. Maybe something like EmptyCommandLine or FailedCommandLine(ex)
        // 3) Make cmd nullable and return null.

        CommandLine() // or, error("Unable to parse options!")
    }

    val inputArg = cmd.getOptionValue("someArg")
}
```

Comment: The 2nd approach is very interesting, thank you for the answer. Just a minor problem with that and that's if you can't initiate the object in catch block (`CommandLine()`) then I don't see any other option than `throw ex` which is not what I really want.

Comment: But what would you expect to happen then?

Comment: @Yar In that case, you could just return null from the catch block and make `cmd` nullable.